# customizing shortcuts of Firefox

Tags: firefox

As you can see, I have so many question about customizing Firefox.

- I wonder how I can set shortcuts used in Firefox .
- Are there any extensions for this purpose ?
- In advance level, how can I customize Firefox shortcuts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has an add on called Customizable Shortcuts that does that.  To get it [Just Click Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/)

Comment: how can I close the shorcut ? thanks for answer.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: sorry, close  = disable

Comment: Highlight the desired shortcut, click on the `edit` button, and then press `delete` on the keyboard.

Comment: @Mitch: That makes the <kbd>del</kbd> key the hotkey for that entry.